# what is the abbreviation of GIT?

Tags: git, abbreviation

In the manual, GIT is "the stupid content tracker". The abbreviation of "the stupid content tracker" is not GIT. I doubt about what the abbreviation of GIT.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's fluff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note: git is spelled 'git' (for the command) or Git (for the product).
Not "GIT", since it is *not* an acronym, but rather an expression of intent: a tool which does "just" version control without trying to be smart (and include tons of other features)
See for instance "[`git-merge-stupid.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2276aa6c098a0337bc2bec49742e332bdd1b802c#diff-61479a6b097e78ecff107e0038fc423d)"

Note that the more [recent 2016 commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28513c4f56a2164fd6d3a16ceddbab3a5bf3f191) remove that title:

```
-Git - the stupid content tracker
-================================
+Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
```

> "the stupid content tracker" was true in the early days of Git, but
>   hardly applicable these days. "fast, scalable, distributed" describes
>   Git more accurately.
>
> Also, "stupid" can be seen as offensive by some people. Let's not use it
>   in the very first words of the README.
>
> The new formulation is taken from the description of the Debian package.

This started in 2007 already with [commit e19b91b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e19b91b4ea8479da3bb3cd600c94d63d04bb8ac2) (13 Feb 2007) by Nicolas Pitre.

> Update RPM core package description (Git isn't as stupid as it used to be)

The original description was:

> This is a stupid (but extremely fast) directory content manager.
>   It doesn't do a whole lot, but what it *does* do is track directory contents efficiently. It is intended to be the base of an efficient, distributed source code management system. This package includes rudimentary tools that can be used as a SCM, but you should look elsewhere for tools for ordinary humans layered on top of this.

Replaced with:

> Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
>    unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
>    and full access to internals.

Answer (score 34):

According to the [initial commit to the git tree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290/README):

> "git" can mean anything, depending on your mood.
>
> - random three-letter combination that is pronounceable, and not    actually used by any common UNIX command.  The fact that it is a   mispronounciation of "get" may or may not be relevant.
> - stupid. contemptible and despicable. simple. Take your pick from the    dictionary of slang.
> - "global information tracker": you're in a good mood, and it actually    works for you. Angels sing, and a light suddenly fills the room.
> - "goddamn idiotic truckload of sh*t": when it breaks

Comment: This should be the answer... +1

Comment: Git starnds for global information tracker